# HEC-GeoHMS Outlet Point Connectivity

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hydrology, modelling, hec-geohms, hec-hms

The "Check Data" option in HMS tab of HEC-GeoHMS is showing a problem in the VIP relevance points which is as follows:

> Checking project points [VIP points]...   Checking VIP Point: Outlet1
> x=276681.7428, y=2711284.2531   End of checking point: name=Outlet1
> oid=1 - PROBLEM: outlet point does not have right river connectivity.
> End of checking project points [VIP points].

I don't understand what it means.